# UITapGestureRecognizer throws process finished with error code 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have a label with gesture recognizer (might be a button with a target), here's code example

```
- (void)addStartText:(UIView *)view :(UIImageView *)image {
UILabel *btnStart = [[UILabel alloc]init];
btnStart.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(image.frame), CGRectGetMidY(image.frame) - 20,
CGRectGetWidth(image.frame), 40);

btnStart.text = @"xxx";
btnStart.textColor = [UIColor pxColorWithHexValue:@"ff0066"];

btnStart.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Impact" size:33];
btnStart.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[btnStart setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(test:)];
[btnStart addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

[view addSubview:btnStart];

self.btnStart = btnStart;

[self addDescription :btnStart :view];
}
```

and receiver method :

```
- (void)test:(id)test {

}
```

and when i touch my label, i throws Process finished with exit code 0,

where's a problem,

thank you !

Comment: I think the problem is in test method. Try it
- (void)test:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

}

Comment: unfortunately, no, it crashes

Comment: If it crashes, please paste the error message from the debugger. I'd strongly recommend that you review your method naming. `- (void)addStartText:(UIView *)view :(UIImageView *)image` => `- (void)addStartTextToView:(UIView *)view withImage:(UIImageView *)image` and for `[self addDescription :btnStart :view];` => `-(void)addDescriptionButton:(UIButton*)button toView:(UIView *)view`

Comment: Not really anywhere your solution, but is seems to me that you are reinventing the button with UILabel. Why don't you use UIButton ?